# Drupal provision module and drush?

Tags: drupal, module, drush

I'm trying to automate the use of the provision drush extension. Mostly that works well, but I can't make a custom drush extension perform a provision-install command, unless I manually use proc_open to call drush again directly.

To keep my code consistent, and use drush's API as much as possible, I would like to avoid any direct spawning of new processes.

So: what I want to work is the call I use for other drush commands, which is
drush_backend_process('@sitealias', 'provision-install', array());"

1) Why does this work for other commands using @aliases, but not provision-install?
2) How well can I make it work, within drush's API? (So as to avoid direct use of proc_open)

More info in this issue: https://drupal.org/node/1844038

Comment: The author of Drush is a regular visitor to the [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/) website, it might be worth flagging your question for migration. Please don't just ask the question again over there, cross-posting isn't allowed :)

Comment: Ok but I am sure that some great drupalers answer to queries here too!